# variables and functions naming convention in c applications

Tags: c, coding-style

I have made a C application using vs 2010 and have followed lowercase with underscores as the naming convention for variables and functions in the application. I am asked to follow the camel case in the entire application. I want to ask whether this is the correct approach for the naming convention in c if yes then Is there any tool that can convert all the variables and functions to camel case in the existing c application.

Comment: There is no "correct" naming convention. While CamelCase isn't popular in C and is not used in the standard library, if your project manager requires it, then you'd better follow suit.

Comment: yeah i will follow the suite but for that need to know if there exist any tool withing vs 2010 or outside in any test editor to convert variable names into camel case.

Comment: Lesson learned: as a professional programmer, make sure that you have decided on a coding standard before writing a single line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding standards vary from company to company. Most mature companies have one, and there is probably some old code lying about somewhere that doesn't follow it.

As long as the coding is done to a consistent style, so you know the name of the function that checks if the car-door is open in your application, whether it is called `car_door_open`, `CarDoorOpen`, `cardoorisopen` matters a lot less. The key is consistency.

I'm not aware of a tool that can rename all identifiers in your code, but modern IDE's have a "rename this identifier", which can be really helpful for these type of things.